# Parsing XML with BeautifulSoup and handling missing element

Tags: python, xml, exception, beautifulsoup

I am using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html) to parse XML:

```
xml = """<person>
<first_name>Matt</first_name>
</person>"""

soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(xml)
first_name = soup.find('first_name').string
last_name = soup.find('last_name').string
```

But I have a problem when there is no last_name, because it chokes.  Sometimes the feed has it, and sometimes it doesn't.  How do I prevent it from choking?

I don't want to use try/except statements.  I also do not want to use if/else statements.  (Since it'll double the lines of the already-very-long code if I have those statements).

Is there any way to just return "None" if there is no "last_name"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
last_name = soup.find('last_name') and soup.find('last_name').string
```

Very silly, but it does meet your equally silly stated restriction (no `if`).  A bit less silly:

```
last_name_node = soup.find('last_name')
last_name = last_name_node and last_name_node.string
```

and:

```
last_name = getattr(soup.find('last_name'), 'string', None)
```

These two don't have the same overhead as the first.  I think a simple `if` is more readable than any of these, though.

Comment: I prefer the getattr version of your answer because I believe that's exactly what getattr was created in the first place!

Comment: @alex: Oh, no! My source code files have lots of linefeed characters in them. Whatever will I do?

Comment: @alex: Perhaps you might like to explain (by editing your question) with an example what you mean by "double the lines" and how this would happen with Alex Martelli's `getattr` suggestion. Using the default arg of `getattr` (or the `get` method of dicts and Elementtree elements) is the usual way of avoiding an `if` or `try` in a readable-enough manner.

Comment: @John, I think @alex is referring only to my suggestion that `if` can be more readable!